# VBA in Outlook: "microsoft outlook has stopped working" message

Tags: vba, outlook

I try to write a VBA script which replys automatically on mails which are in the inbox of a shared mailbox. At the moment it's just a test, later on I want to reply on new incoming mails.
However, so far if I try to run the code, Outlook crashes with the error "microsoft outlook has stopped working" and I have to restart Outlook.

fyi: I'm using a German Outlook Version 2007.

```
Sub ReplyMail()

Dim myOutApp As Object
Dim myNameSpace As Object
Dim myMailFolder As Object
Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient

boxName = "sharedmailbox@host.de"      'configure mailbox address here

'Get Mailbox folder
Set myOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set myNameSpace = myOutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myRecipient = myNameSpace.CreateRecipient(boxName)
    myRecipient.Resolve         'convert mail address into mailbox name
Set myMailFolder = myNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderInbox)

Dim Item As Object
Set Item = myMailFolder.Items(1)

Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set oMail = Item.Reply
With oMail
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .HTMLBody = "<HTML>This is a test mail.</HTML>"     
    .Send
End With

End Sub
```

If use ".display" instead of ".send" the mail pops up correctly and I'm able to send the mail manually.

I really don't know how to solve this error, pls help!

Thank you!

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Very strange! 
Unless it's an exceptional bug, I don't see it. 
Small remark: Declare your objects as Outlook objects:

```
Dim myOutapp as outlook.application 
Dim myNameSpace as outlook.namespace
Dim myMailFolder as Mapifolder
```

This for general performance (Object is the general type) but it will almost certainly not solve your problem.

If I were in your situation, I'd try to entirely quit Outlook from memory, repair or reinstall Outlook/Office. I don't think that something is terribly wrong with your code; Since the .display works, I'm very surprised.

Comment: Another interesting thing is, that the reply-mail appears after I restart the chrashed Outlook.

In other forums I read that some people get a security message, that some programm wants to send an email automatically, but I don't. Could be there the problem?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I have done some automations sending automatic emails and retrieving mails from mailboxes (also functional mailboxes on a network) while processing attachments and I have never faced any problems with this. I have read on the internet about other people having had problems in Outlook automation, sometimes resolved after re-installment or repairment of the OL application. Is it not possible for you to display instead of send? In the previous company I worked for it was even against the general rules to send mails automatically without explicit revision before sending.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with access rights to
C:\Users\

I had a similar issue with opening certain e-mails starting from a certain point of time. Somehow access rights to that folder had been deconfigured.
So I followed this procedure and everything was fine again:
http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7-access-denied-permission-ownership/

Comment: You could improve your answer by incorporating at least some information from the link, in case it breaks some day.